# How to see form data that I am posting on Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am working on Sinatra, is there a way to see the form data that I am posting to an action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
params.inspect
```

Or for just the post data (the above also includes GET parameters)

```
request.POST.inspect
```